# jqPlot: Remove decimals from x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

How do I make the x-axis display only integers instead on jqPlot?

Currently it reads:

```
0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, etc.
```

I want to force it to only display integers in the x-axis labels.

Answer (score 8):

You might need to specify a format string:

```
 axes: {
  xaxis: {
    tickOptions: {
      formatString: "%d"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It says I can accept your answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: This sort of works. Since it doesn't hide non-whole numbers, only changes their values, a problem arises on axes with a small range. Instead of `0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0...` you will see `0, 1, 1, 2, 2...`